# Split paragraph at every instance of a number?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, split

I have paragraph text like:

"2 lb thawed chicken breasts1/2 cup jarred red salsa try and choose a basic 2 carbs/2 tbs option- we love the double roasted from Trader Joes5 cloves garlic minced I use the frozen dorot cubes every time!1 tbs liquid smoke sold near bottled barbecue sauce at any normal store1-2 tbs chipotle peppers in adobo sauce."

That I would like to look like this

- 2 lb thawed chicken breasts
- 1/2 cup jarred red salsa try and choose a basic 2 carbs/2 tbs option-
  we love the double roasted from Trader Joes
- 5 cloves garlic minced I use the frozen dorot cubes every time!
- 1-2 tbs chipotle peppers in adobo sauce.

I understand it might be impossible to distringuish between the serving amounts and just random numbers in the text but I can go through and correct those instances.

I have tried the following:

```
function makeList(text){
    let textString = new String(text)
    let newText = textString.split(/(?=\d+(\/\d+|\.\d+))/g)
    return newText
}
```

but it doesn't seem to split the paragraph correctly.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you look at the text and manually add line breaks, what rules do you follow to create your desired result?

Answer (score 3):

If it is not a must to match the right number form with the right unit, you might get all the matches using:

```
\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)? (?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs).*?(?=\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)? (?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs)|$)
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional part that matches either `/` or `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs)` Match a space and any of the alternatives
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right it

  - `\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)? (?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs)` The number and unit pattern
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG4I54/1)

```js
const regex = /\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)? (?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs).*?(?=\d+(?:[\/-]\d+)? (?:lb|cup|cloves|tbs)|$)/gm;
const str = `2 lb thawed chicken breasts1/2 cup jarred red salsa try and choose a basic 2 carbs/2 tbs option- we love the double roasted from Trader Joes5 cloves garlic minced I use the frozen dorot cubes every time!1 tbs liquid smoke sold near bottled barbecue sauce at any normal store1-2 tbs chipotle peppers in adobo sauce.`;
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the numbers you want to split on does NOT follow a space, a slash or a hyphen.

In that case you can use this regex:

```
/(?<![ /-])(?=\d)/g
```

The regex starts by using a `negative look behind` for a `space`, a `slash` or a `hyphen` - meaning 'don't match on numbers following one of these. Of course you can add/remove other characters here.

It then uses a `positive look ahead` for a `digit`  meaning it will match an empty string, used for splitting.

```js
let text = '2 lb thawed chicken breasts1/2 cup jarred red salsa try and choose a basic 2 carbs/2 tbs option- we love the double roasted from Trader Joes5 cloves garlic minced I use the frozen dorot cubes every time!1 tbs liquid smoke sold near bottled barbecue sauce at any normal store1-2 tbs chipotle peppers in adobo sauce.';

let regex = /(?<![ /-])(?=\d)/g;

let lines = text.split(regex);

console.log(lines);
```